# PowerShell Azure Function: list Storage A/c blobs = unauthorised

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-functions, vnet

The following PS code works when targeting a storage account that is open to all networks:

```
Set-AzCurrentStorageAccount -ResourceGroupName $azResourceGroupName  -Name $azStorageAccountName
@files=@()
Get-AzStorageBlob -Container $azContainerName -Prefix 'myfolder' | Select Name | where-object -Property Name -match 'txt' -outvariable files
```

However when applied via Azure function targeting a storage account that is locked down to private endpoint access it does not.

Error:

> The client 'REDACTED1234' with object id 'REDACTED1234' does not have
> authorization to perform action
> 'Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/read' over scope
> '/subscriptions/mySub/resourceGroups/my-rg/providers/Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/myStorageAccount123'
> or the scope is invalid. If access was recently granted, please
> refresh your credentials.

The function app has a system assigned managed identity with contributor and blob storage contributor roles.

profile.ps1 is unchanged:

```
if ($env:MSI_SECRET) {
    Disable-AzContextAutosave -Scope Process | Out-Null
    Connect-AzAccount -Identity}
```

The function and storage a/c's sit in a separate Vnets with Vnet peering enabled.

I'm suspicious of the vnet peering but it's not something I have much experience in - any suggestions?

If anyone can point to PS code calling a blob private endpoint I'd be most grateful.

Comment: So you configured the managed identity settings in the profile.ps1 file?

Comment: profile.ps1 is unchanged but uncommented (added to text above).

Comment: Is your storage account is enabled with a firewall?

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/PNHnSUY.png - Have you added your function app VNet in Storage Account > Networking > Selected Networks > add existing Virtual network ?

Comment: @HariKrishna and Dilly B: Public access is disabled.  Private endpoint should be the only route.

Comment: @felixmc, Are you following this [MS tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-create-vnet) for the above scenario?

Comment: @HariKrishna not exactly but the activites contained mirror what I've done.  [This is closer](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/apps-on-azure-blog/secure-storage-account-linked-to-function-app-with-private/ba-p/2644772)

Comment: Follow up to say I suspect DNS.  Have taken another route via restricted logic app call.

Comment: I have been trying using the provided MS Doc, getting 503 service unavailable. It's good to listen the follow up comment and could you post your alternate solution, which would help to community members if they would face similar issues.

Comment: Sure @HariKrishna. We needed security but as I say, private endpoint not working as expected.  Alternative, logic app with public access has option to use firewall that can restrict to IPs etc.  Also, logic app can have policy which validates calls to it has valid bearer token.  See [here](https://gotoguy.blog/2020/12/31/protect-logic-apps-with-azure-ad-oauth-part-1-management-access/comment-page-1/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @*felixmc* for providing an alternative workaround as a solution for the current context i.e.

Getting Unauthorized when trying to access Storage account (with private endpoint) via Function App.

> Logic app with public access has option to use firewall that can restrict to IPs etc. Also, logic app can have policy which validates calls to it has valid bearer token.

Above alternative solution is taken from the ***GoToGuy Blog*** [article](https://gotoguy.blog/2020/12/31/protect-logic-apps-with-azure-ad-oauth-part-1-management-access/comment-page-1/) provided by the user @*felixmc* that Azure Logic Apps can be secured with the help of restricting Inbound IP addresses and also with the Azure Active Directory OAuth Policy process using the Bearer Token where a practical workaround is shown in the same article provided by the author @*AndreasMunch*.